# Best tools/technologies to ingest data from millions of IOT devices to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, iot, data-ingestion

Could any one suggest best way to ingest millions of messages from IOT devices (sensors/mobile etc) to a kafka topic in my server? Best w.r.t cost, scalability & throughput.
Kafka cluster is hosted in AWS.

We tried devices -> ALB -> NiFi -> Kafka , devices -> ALB -> GO Lang -> Kafka

Any other better architecture?

Thanks
MH

Comment: What challenges do you face? What is your current throughput?

Comment: minifi + nifi seems like a fine way to go...

Comment: With NiFi we are achieving 3-4K per sec, but NiFi licensing cost is more.
With Golang we are able to achieve much better, still looking for better options..